# iPerf and Port Forwarding WAN and LAN

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, iperf, iperf3

I'll do my best to explain this setup correctly

I have my iPerf server listening on port 5201
IP of the pc running the server is 10.xxx.xxx.131
PC is connected to a modem (default gateway 10.xxx.xxx.129)

Modem is connected to a router (WAN 10.xxx.xxx.134 and LAN default gateway of 192.168.1.1)
Behind the router are my client devices (192.168.1.xxx) running iPerf and trying to connect to the server.

I am trying to port forward but not able to find the correct solution.

Port Forwarding Options (on router):
External Port:
Internal Port:
Protocol: TCP+UDP
Loopback:

iPerf on Client device:
Server Address: 10.xxx.xxx.131
Server Port: 5201

Comment: What is the make and model of the "modem"? It sounds like it's more than just a modem, and that would make a big difference regarding how to design the network downstream of it. If it's doing NAT, you don't need your downstream router to do NAT, so you can make your network one flat network and not have to deal with crossing a NAT within your own home LAN.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add a basic diagram? If I understand your description correctly, iperf should work fine by default (without any port forwarding), since the clients initiate the connection. What error are you seeing?

Comment: @Spiff - Its a Hitron EN2251. And unfortunately this is where my network knowledge just drops off a cliff. This is the setup that I have to have for this type of testing, so I can't really change it. Is there a way to get this connection to work. Is this a double NAT issue?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale only error I see is just "cannot connect to the server, please check that the server is running". This is on iPerf3 on a phone. Server is running.

Comment: Hmm. The Hitron EN2251 is just a DOCSIS modem, which makes this weirder. Did you put a switch between the modem and the router? (I ask because cable modems generally aren't designed to handle that; they expect to be cabled directly to a single router via Ethernet.) Did the modem provide IP addresses to the iperf server PC AND the router at the same time? What subnet mask and default gateway address are the iperf server PC and the router's WAN port using?

Comment: 10.xxx.xxx.134 might indicate its CGN? Not the 'right' range, they should be using 100.x.x.x but apparently not.